# How can I prevent a mobile device from dimming the screen or sleeping in A-Frame?

Tags: android, html, google-cardboard, aframe, webvr

When viewing A-Frame in stereoscopic view on my Android phone with a Cardboard-like viewer, the screen dims and then shuts off.  I know that I can change this in Android settings, but is there an HTML way to prevent a screen from dimming or shutting off?  Also, when not in stereoscopic view, I don't have this problem because a touch event keeps the screen active.

Comment: We do include wakelock.js, but an issue may need to be filed if it is not working.

Comment: Do I have to explicitly enable it?

Comment: I filed an issue for this on GitHub.

Comment: I don't know the reason for it, but it seems to be fixed after upgrading from Android 6 to 7.